# How to interpolate a wrapped/circular grid with xarray?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I'm trying to interpolate a global grid to a finer grid but when I use `ds.interp()` I don't know how to specify that `'lon'` is a wrapped/circular variable (not sure what the correct term is). Below I replicated my problem with some random data. When I interpolate you can see that the edges of `ds_new` become NaN values. For the top and bottom, this is okay (and understandable) however for the `'lon'` dimension it should connect the 0 and 359 values and not make NaN values on the edges (see the plot on the right).

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lon = np.linspace(0, 354.4, 64)
lat = np.linspace(-87.2, 87.2, 32)

data = np.random.rand(32,64)

da = xr.DataArray(data=data, dims=["lat", "lon"], coords=[lat,lon])
ds = da.to_dataset(name='data')

new_lon = np.linspace(0, 359, 360)
new_lat = np.linspace(-89.5, 89.5, 180)

ds_new = ds.interp(lat=new_lat, lon=new_lon, method='linear')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(16, 4))
ds.data.plot(ax=axes[0])
ds_new.data.plot(ax=axes[1])
```

[image: data plot]

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't a way to tell xarray that a coordinate is periodic, but it is in our roadmap to support that.

Unfortunately that first requires a considerable refactor to allow coordinate variables to wrap any kind of indexes, not just pandas indexes. That is planned to happen in the next 6 months or so, and you can track the progress of that effort on the [project page](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/projects/1).

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I solved the problem using cdo remapbil for now but I'll keep an eye on the process and switch to xarray when this is implemented.